# Fixing typescript warnings when inferring react props types from map of string=>type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've got a React component called `Field` which is intended to render various types of form inputs, including custom inputs implemented through other React components. The type of input is determined by `type`, which can be a known string (`keyof FIELD_TYPES`, which in turn determines the React component to create) or any kind of React component (functional or class based). This is already implemented, but I've encountered a few issues when trying to provide proper typings for the implementation. Note that one of the goals is to ensure that the props are correctly inferred, so that intellisense can suggest valid attributes on the resulting element.

[This codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-inferred-react-props-u8o03?file=/src/index.tsx:406-417) showcases 3 different Typescript warnings that I'm trying to fix. Each issue is annotated with a `// FIXME` comment;

**(1) & (2):** Type X cannot be used to index type 'Y' - I've so far been unable to figure out a way to satisfy Typescript here.

**(3):** Custom components aren't accepted by Typescript - Not sure how to modify the typings to allow this.

I've also tried using discriminating unions, but got stuck trying to infer props of the component passed as `type` or resolved through the `FIELD_TYPES` map. An answer utilizing this approach would also work great.

```
const FIELD_TYPES = {
  text: "input",
  checkbox: "input",
  textarea: "textarea",
  custom: Custom
} as const;
type FieldTypeMap = typeof FIELD_TYPES

type KeysOfType<T, K> = { [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends K ? I : never }[keyof T]

type ReactComponentType<P = any> = React.ComponentType<P> | React.ExoticComponent<P>

type FieldTypeProps<Props = any> =
  | { type?: KeysOfType<FieldTypeMap, 'input'> } & JSX.IntrinsicElements['input']
  // FIXME(4): Is there any way to DRY this up?
  | { type: 'textarea' } & JSX.IntrinsicElements['textarea']
  | { type: 'select' } & JSX.IntrinsicElements['select']
  // FIXME(5+6): How to include props for the provided react component type?
  | { type: ReactComponentType<Props> } & Props // FIXME(5)
  | { type: KeysOfType<FieldTypeMap, ReactComponentType<Props>> } & {} // FIXME(6)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first reactions: keep `custom` out of `FieldTypeMap` and handle those differently.  Removing it actually fixes one the error "FIXME(1)".  Regarding "FIXME(2)", the issue there is that automatic type guards don't work when joined with `&&`.  You would have to check each thing separately.

Comment: I just tried writing something very similar via overloads for another question and I could not get it quite right: http://tsplay.dev/rw2j1w

Comment: For "FIXME(4)": `type PropsUnion = {    [K in keyof FieldTypeMap]: { type: K } & JSX.IntrinsicElements[FieldTypeMap[K]]   }`

Comment: Thank you for the help Linda, much appreciated! I'll see if I can make any additional improvements, if so I'll come back with a follow up in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that you need to split custom components from instrinsic input types, so you can map the props. Also, because you're overloading the existing "type" prop, you need to omit it.

Here's the now working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-inferred-react-props-forked-hrh8p?file=/src/index.tsx